# How to draw a Image in child's view through paintEvent

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a Chinese and poor in English,so I show the code to express myself.

```
class Widget:public QWidget 
{
private:
//As a child object of Widget object
    QLabel* label; 

};

// Override the paintEvent
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
 //How to  draw a picture in the QLabel not in the full  Widget's view,thx!!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to initialize your label in constructor, add something like this:

```
void Widget::Widget()
{
   label=new QLabel(this);
}
```

and then your paintEvent do something like this -

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    // create QPixmap or QImage object or how else you store it and load it to label
    QImage img("./myimage.jpg");
    label->setPixmap(img.pixmap());
}
```

and it will be drawn on tha label, but by default label has growing sizePolicy - it will be  resized to fill as many space as possibly if your widget doesn't have any other objects - your label will take the whole space, so it will be good to add your QLabel to some of the layouts (`QGridLayout`) and you need to `setSizePolicy` of your QLabel to `QSizePolicy::Maximum`

Comment: already updated answer, it's layout and SizePolicy is what confuses you

Comment: Thx,I have worked it out !!!! Thank you very much. I almost take one day to try to solve it !!!Without your help, I will keep thinking...

Comment: you are welcome, had the same problem a long time ago, and still remember the frustration :)